# React dropzone image not updated on template

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used react dropzone component for multiple image upload but the image preview is not shown on my template.Files are shown on console.Where have i done wrong? I have used this component from here https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone . let me know what else i have to provide to examine this issue with fine-tooth comb. Thanks for help in advance. Your help will be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

export default class DropzoneDemo extends Dropzone {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      files: [],
      style: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.style = {
      backgroundImage: (`url(${this.props.img})`),
    };
    this.state.files = [];
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.files.length) {
      this.state.style = {
        backgroundImage: (`url(${this.state.files[0].preview})`),
      };
    } else {
      this.state.style = {
        backgroundImage: (`url(${this.props.img})`),
      };
    }
  }

  onDrop(files) {
    console.log(this.state.files);
    this.state.files = files;
  }

  render() {
    const emptyStyle = {
      backgroundImage: 'none',
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} style={emptyStyle} >
          <div className='wrap-to-drag-img' style={this.state.style}></div>
        </Dropzone>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't update this.state directly like this in React

```
this.state.style = { // this is bad
        backgroundImage: (`url(${this.state.files[0].preview})`),
      };
```

Set the style in render() instead

```
render() {
  const bgImage = this.state.files.length ?             
       `url(${this.state.files[0].preview})` :
       `url(${this.props.img})`;
  const bgStyle = {
     backgroundImage: bgImage
  };

  const emptyStyle = {
    backgroundImage: 'none',
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} style={emptyStyle} >
        <div className='wrap-to-drag-img' style={bgStyle}></div>
      </Dropzone>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onDrop(files) {
    this.state.files = files;
    console.log(files[0].preview);
    const bgImage = this.state.files.length ?
      `url(${this.state.files[0].preview})` :
      `url(${this.props.img})`;
    const bgStyle = {
      backgroundImage: bgImage,
    };
    const emptyStyle = {
      backgroundImage: 'none',
    };
    const dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
    ReactDOM.render(<div id='dropzone'><Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} style={emptyStyle} >
      <div className='wrap-to-drag-img' style={bgStyle}></div>
    </Dropzone></div>, dropzone);
  }
```